# Recently reloaded computer, now have trailing effect when windows overlap

Tags: windows-7

I recently did a clean install of my home machine and I am having a weird graphical error where if I move one window across the top of another it leaves a trail:

[image]

I have the most recent NVIDIA drivers installed and nothing new is installed on my machine than before the reload (and I never had this issue before). I have two monitors and it happens on both so I'm sure it isn't a hardware issue (the card and my main monitor are also both less than 6 months old) I've also noticed a ripple when scrolling down on web pages which I believe is related.

Any ideas what might be causing this and solutions to fix it?

Comment: Windows Starter does not support extended desktop for multiple monitors. Did you choose the Windows Basic theme yourself? If not, you may be missing other drivers if Windows 7 thinks your computer can't handle the Aero theme, and if you are experiencing these graphical artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

This really sounds like a driver issue.
Try updating your chipset drivers, and the uninstall and reinstall the driver for your graphics card.

Comment: +1 **All** drivers, not just chipset and graphics.